# Is it secure to encrypt with EC "for myself"?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

I want to encrypt some small amount of data using ECDH for use by myself later, but I don't want to generate an ephemeral keypair like in ECIES, due to time and space constraints.

Would it be safe to use *my existing* EC keypair to encrypt data "for myself"?

In this case I don't need to store any key material with the ciphertext, which is nice.

But is it secure?
Alternatively I could just hash my private key and use that as the symmetric key. Would that be more or less secure?

---

The encryption goes as follows. Let $P$ be my public point on the curve secp256k1 and let $P=[d]G$ hold with $d$ being my private key. I encrypt a message $m$ as follows:

1. I perform an ECDH agreement with my own public key, i.e. compute $S=[d]P$
2. I hash the common point with SHA256 to get the key $K=H(S)$
3. I generate a 16 byte IV uniformly at random using a CSPRNG: $IV\xleftarrow{\$}\{0,1\}^{128}$
4. I encrypt the message using AES-256-CBC as $c=E_{K,IV}(m)$
5. I return $(IV,c)$, knowing that I can re-derive $K$ using only my key-pair

Comment: Use authenticated encryption, not AES-CBC!  If you use a _distinct_ hash of your private key from any hash used by any other application of your private key, that's probably fine to make a symmetric key.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Using a KDF would be better, with a unique random number (salt) stored with the ciphertext to derive the key maybe (HKDF would be nice and it accepts a label / info and salt). As a complete alternative, use ECIES but sign the data before encryption with e.g. AES in counter mode. CBC should not be used anymore imho.

Comment: I agree with Poncho here. Although the question tries to reinvent ECIES it seems to me that using ECIES for personal use is the answer that we're looking for. It can be secure and doesn't require the private key during encryption if just confidentiality is required.

Comment: If I wanted to use ECIES, there would be no need to ask this question. Unfortunately for my application ECIES is too heavy (performance and spacewise), hence the question.

Comment: 'ECIES is too heavy'; but your encryption procedure is mostly ECIES (except that real ECIES includes a symmetric integrity transform, such as a MAC or authenticated encryption)

Comment: @poncho - ECIES requires me to generate an ephemeral keypair and include the ephemeral public key with the ciphertext. That would triple the size of my payload. I don't need any MAC, too (that's handled at another level).

Comment: $S=[d]P$ sounds really dangerous. Imagine somebody replaying your public key to you. Then they could let you perform other operations with the same key material. If you need the private key you are certainly better off using HKDF with the private key, a special label and a salt. Or combine the two methods and perform the special KDF over $S$.

Comment: @rustyx You can use a compressed point for the public key and you can leave out the MAC if you just want confidentiality with ECIES. Use the ephemeral public key as IV or use a zero IV if you regenerate the ephemeral key pair (and thus the secret key) each time any way.

Comment: An ephemeral key seems to be needed for [PFS](https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy). Haven't thought about that. Indeed I want PFS so will use the full ECDH with a compressed key.